# sign language recognition system using CNN it resulting wrong predictions

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, training-data

i working on ASL Sign language recognition system based on CNN, i developed the basic code (which is training the dataset) in google colab, then i used python 3.8.0 to loading the trained models and test them to see how CNN work. My problem: when i start to try my system and i doing the hand guster of a letter, the system did not predict the correct character!! it just 2 of charecters was correctly predicted. i think the model did not trained well,  but i did not know how can i fix it. Also,  i am still learning deep learning so i do not have enough experince, i don't sure if i build the CNN correctly
This is basic code (google colab):

```
!pip install kaggle
! mkdir ~/.kaggle
!cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle
!chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!kaggle datasets download -d ayuraj/asl-dataset

import zipfile
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import shutil
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19

zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("/content/asl-dataset.zip", 'r')
zip_ref.extractall("/content/")
zip_ref.close() 

os.mkdir("test")
for dir in os.listdir("/content/asl_dataset"):
  os.mkdir("/content/test/" + dir)

for f2 in os.listdir("asl_dataset"):#split dataset
    for i in range(10):
        shutil.move("asl_dataset/" + f2+"/" + os.listdir("asl_dataset/" + f2)[i], "test/" + f2)

train_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale = 1./255,
      shear_range = 0.2,
      zoom_range = 0.2,
      horizontal_flip = True
)

test_dataset = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/content/asl_dataset/',
        target_size = (224,224),
        batch_size = 16)
validation_generator = test_dataset.flow_from_directory(
        '/content/test/',
        target_size = (224,224),
        batch_size = 16)


vgg_model = VGG19(weights="imagenet",include_top=False,input_shape=(224,224,3))
for layer in vgg_model.layers:
  layer.trainable = False
print(len(vgg_model.layers))
vgg_model.summary()


#CNN
Flat_layer = Flatten()(vgg_model.layers[21].output)
FC_layer = Dense(128)(Flat_layer)    
Act_layer = Activation('relu')(FC_layer)
Class_layer = Dense(36)(Act_layer)    
Softmax_layer = Activation('softmax')(Class_layer)   
model = Model(inputs=vgg_model.inputs, outputs=Softmax_layer)
model.summary()

adam = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              validation_data=validation_generator,
                              epochs=30)

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()


model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

i tried ti change the size of images to 300*300 also i tried to set epcho= 5 insted of 30, also i set the class in CNN as Dense(26) but nothing work

i need to make my system to predict the char correctly and fast. please help me